# ordering by two columns from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below select query and I would like to order the result by desc from each table with the column `id` and `thread_id.` The where clause only applies to `messages` table. I need `order by id, thread_id desc` Can someone help me out?
 I guess I need to select from both tables first.

```
 $stmt = $msg->prepare("
     SELECT * FROM messages
     where to_user = ?
           and deleted != ?
           and del2 != ?
           or from_user = ?
           and conversation = 'true'
           and deleted != ?
           and del2 != ?
     order by id desc");
```

My `thread` table looks like something:

```
thread_id(INT)   
thread_to_user   
thread_from_user
thread_message....
```

My `messages` table looks like something:

```
id(INT)   
to_user   
from_user
message
deleted
del2
date
conversation....
```

Currently I am only selecting from `messages` table and echoing new messages. the second table is for threaded message, so if the users start conversation then the msg goes to `thread` table and what I am trying to do is to order the messages in `messages` table by the `thread_id` and `id` so if new reply comes the it goes to top.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... do you want to join in the `thread` table into your query?

Comment: @user623952 yeah something like that, I don't know maybe `LEFT JOIN` I didn't do multiple select as I have no idea.

Comment: do you miss some parentheses? `WHERE (to_user = ? and deleted != ? and del2 != ?) OR (from_user = ? and conversation = 'true' and deleted != ? and del2 != ?)` ?

Comment: @fthiella My code doesn't have that actually but I will put it if it is necessary.

Comment: @user3006683. you should share you tables structure, show some sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want but if you want to show the `thread` and `order by ID` then you could probably try this:

```
SELECT id, m.to_user, m.from_user, message, deleted, del2, date, conversation, 
thread_id, thread_to_user, thread_from_user, thread_message 
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN thread t
ON m.from_user = t.thread_from_user
where (to_user = ?
      or from_user = ?)
      and deleted != ?
      and del2 != ?
      and conversation = 'true'
      and deleted != ?
      and del2 != ?
order by thread_id
```

I change the order of `OR` also as I grouped it with `to_user.`